# Swagger Integration in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, swagger, swagger-ui

I need to integrate Swagger in Django. So, can anyone discuss the steps to integrate Swagger in Django. I need the full description.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Swagger is tool for documenting your API. Django by default serves templates not API.

Comment: Django can serve APIs too: it simply lets you compose responses for given URL patterns. Moreover, Django Rest Framework is designed specifically to ease creation of APIs on top of Django applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to use Swagger, then I'm sure you're building an API (REST). So answering to your wide range question about Swagger integration with Django, you can use Django Rest Framework + Swagger (which I recommend) or Swagger only. What you need to do in this case:

### Django Rest Framework + Swagger

```
pip install django djangorestframework django-rest-swagger
```

then in your `settings.py` just include:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
]
```

then in your `urls.py`:

```
from rest_framework import routers

from yourapp.accounts.views import UserViewSet


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    ...
]
```

in `views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list` and `detail` actions.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

and after entering home page `/`, you will get swagger interface with all endpoints rendered (registered in router as in the example above).

### Django + Swagger

```
pip install django django-rest-swagger
```

then in your `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    ...
]
```

in `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from views import schema_view


urlpatterns = [
    url('/', schema_view),
    ...
]
```

and in your example `views.py`:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes
from rest_framework import response, schemas
from rest_framework_swagger.renderers import OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer


@api_view()
@renderer_classes([OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer])
def schema_view(request):
    generator = schemas.SchemaGenerator(title='Bookings API')
    return response.Response(generator.get_schema(request=request))
```

Reference:

[Django REST Swagger](https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/)